# how to create custom helper with class (css) options in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create helper that return the avatar linked to the user.

for that i do:

```
<%= basic_avatar(user)%>
```

and the helper:

```
def basic_avatar(user)
  link_to image_tag(user.avatar) ,'#', :title => user.name
end
```

But now, i want to add some options like attributes, classes etc.
for example, i want to do this:

```
<%= basic_avatar(user, class: 'avatar')%>
```

or:

```
<%= basic_avatar(user, class: 'avatar', name: 'avatar')%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an options hash to helper declaration, and use that when making your image tag. The last argument in the image_tag call is a hash, so you're basically all set.

```
def basic_avatar(user, options={})
  link_to image_tag(user.avatar), "#", options.merge(:title => user.name)
end
```

This makes it so the options is optional, and then they just get passed along to `image_tag`, as well as the title you want.